# Render plot within hidden container element on Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Pretty straightforward problem...I receive an error `Error: unable to start png() device` when trying to render a plot into a non-visible `div` (see example below).

I’ve been trying to approach the issue by creating a shiny module, but not confident that will address the underlying problem.

I have not tried `shinyjs` as yet (cool if that is the solution, but would rather avoid a package dependency, if possible).

As a sidenote, I’d like to avoid rendering into a visible element offscreen/ low z-order to better understand how shiny deals with hidden elements. Note that the actual plot is based on reactive content that may change while the container `div` is hidden, and the resulting plot will need to be interactive (brush/ hover/ etc).

**Update**: I installed the `Cairo` package as an attempted solution, and now receive the error `Error: Failed to create Cairo backend` (have also tried to directly call `png()` and `Cairo()` within an `obeserve({})` block, without any different effect).

### RepEx:

```
require(tidyverse)
require(shiny)

a_plot <- tibble(x=1:10,y=rnorm(10)) %>% ggplot(aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_point()

server <- function(input, session, output) {
  output$p1 <- renderPlot({a_plot})
  output$p2 <- renderPlot({a_plot})
  outputOptions(output,’p2’, suspendWhenHidden=FALSE)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(plotOutput(‘p1’)),
  fluidRow(div(id=‘plot_container’, style=‘display: none’, plotOutput(‘p2’))),
  withTags(head(script(HTML(‘window.onmouseover = function(event) {document.getElementById(“plot_container”).style.display = “block” }’))))
)

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

### Expected Output:

Two plots appear upon mouseover of webpage.

### Environment

`R 3.6.0` on `Windows 10`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifying explicit values for the ‘height’ and ‘width’ parameters of `renderPlot()` will resolve error. See [Shiny github issue #1409](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1409)